# How to loop sharepoint document library subfolders with powershell in CSOM

Tags: powershell

I have this code:

```
    cls
function Recurse ($folder){
  write-host ----- $folder.Name
  $context.Load($folder.Subfolders)
  $context.ExecuteQuery()
          foreach($folder in $folder.Subfolders)
        {
          write-host ---------- $folder.Name 
        }


  # write-host --------------  $folder.Subfolders 
}
function GetChildFolders($RootFolder) 
{
        $context.Load($RootFolder)
        $context.Load($RootFolder.Folders)
        $context.ExecuteQuery()
        write-host $RootFolder.Name 
        foreach($folder in $RootFolder.Folders)
        {
          if($folder.Name -ne "Forms")
          {
           Recurse -folder $folder  
          }
        }
}


function Get-SPOWebs(){
param(
   $Url = $(throw "Please provide a Site Collection Url"),
   $Credential = $(throw "Please provide a Credentials")
)

  $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)  
  $context.Credentials = $Credential 
  $web = $context.Web
  $context.Load($web)
  $context.Load($web.Webs)
  $context.ExecuteQuery()
  foreach($web in $web.Webs)
  {

       Write-Host ""
       Write-Host ""
       Write-Host  ------------- $web.Title -------------
       $lists = $web.lists
       $context.Load($lists) 
       $context.ExecuteQuery() 
        foreach ($list in $lists)
        {
        if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {
           $list.RootFolder
            GetChildFolders -RootFolder $list.RootFolder
            }

        }
       Get-SPOWebs -Url $web.Url -Credential $Credential 
       $web
  }
}
    $loadInfo1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
    $loadInfo2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


$UserName = "User"
$Password = "Pass"
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$SPOCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)

$AllWebs = Get-SPOWebs -Url 'sharepointSiteURL'-Credential $SPOCredentials
```

In Recurse function i want to show subfolders name, but it never loops subfolders.
Thanks.

Comment: help please?? T.T

Comment: hi @Ioni-As  I know this is late, but I have attached an answer for you to look at :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GMasucci, I needed ***GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl*** function to retrieve folders folders.

```
function Recurse ($folder){

   $context.Load($folder)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
     write-host $folder.Name
    $rootURL="https://SPOnlineSite.sharepoint.com"+$folder.ServerRelativeUrl
    $f = $web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($rootURL)
    $context.Load($f)
    $context.Load($f.Folders)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

     createFolder -name $f.ServerRelativeUrl

    SearchFiles -folder $f
    foreach($fold in $f.Folders)
    {
     Recurse -folder $fold
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CSOM (which it looks like) then if you change `subfolders` for `folders`, you should get an iteration of all the folders starting at the one you pass into the function all the way to its furthest leaf..  Below is a small example of a recursive folder function:

```
function global:RecurseFolders([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder] $folderObject, $Context = $null, $tab = "")
{
    if ($Context -eq $null)
    {
        Throw "The Context was Null and you MUST have a context to continue."
    }
    $Context.load($folderObject.folders)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    write-host($tab+$folder.Name)
    $indent="  "
    $tab +=$indent
    foreach($folder in $folderObject.folders)
    {
        $Context.load($folder.files)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        foreach ($file in $folder.files)
        {
            write-host($tab+"-F-"+$file.Name)
        }
        RecurseFolders -folderObject $folder -Context $Context -Tab $tab
    }
}
```

As you can see this also uses a CSOM context and recurses through the child folders, printing out the folder hierarchy in an indented DOS-flavoured way.

Let me know if you need more information and I can expand this.