# Why More files has been migrated to the Sharepoint from fileShare?

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, online, server

Thanks for in advance for the all the answer. I hope you can help me with this one.

So I have migrated about 19.5 GB from fileShare to Sharepoint . It is only one folder that contains 50.704 files and 4.610 folders.I believe, in total it makes **55.314** items.

I have migrated this folder to a one library on a site.  When i checked how many items on the library , I see there are **55.345** Items

So there are 31 items more In Sharepoint than a source of FileShare.

Plus when i see the ItemReport log . There are 8 failed files so it makes 39 items more in Sharepoint.

What could be the problem here guys please?

I really preciate for every answer.

[image: SharePoint Library Item Count]

[image: File Share Folder Properties]

Comment: We aren't able to tell you whats going on, you should create script which will list all folders and files on FileSystem and on SharePoint and compare them.


Otherwise you can add here the migration full log and we can investigate, but probably there are important data.

Which Migration tool have you used?

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška thank you for your help . I have used microsoft migration tool . Yes I am doing this at work so I cant share the logs. What kind of script that i can use please?

Comment: you need two scripts, one for FileSystem, second for SharePoint, you need to list all fiels and folders. For SPO something like: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171359/how-to-loop-sharepoint-document-library-subfolders-with-powershell-in-csom